# How to Tokio::select! futures, but never cancel slow ones

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have one consumer, and the code looks like this:

`consumer.next().await` is used to retrieve a new message.

1. If the new message is similar to the previous one, increment the `count` without actually consuming it.
2. If the new message is different from the previous one, consume the previous message with the `count` and repeat the logic.
3. If no new message arrives within two seconds, consume the previous message with the `count` and continue waiting for the new message.

I am trying to use `tokio::time::timeout` or `tokio::select!`, but it seems that I may lose the message when a timeout occurs.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the "consumer"? If its one of the typical tokio channels then note that `select` is explicitly telling you about this problem, and lists [which primitives](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html#cancellation-safety) can be safely used in this way without loosing messages. If your consumer is NOT cancellation safe, I believe you can do no better than to run two tasks, one which pulls data and pushes it to a shared queue which IS cancellation safe, and the other which performs the logic as described.

Comment: @user2407038, my consumer is Lapin. I am not sure if it is cancellation-safe. So, the best practice is to use mpsc to ensure cancellation safety, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unless the documentation tells you it is cancellation safe, you should assume that it is not. I think the best practice will be based on how important performance is in your application - naturally pushing all your data to an intermediate queue which is cancellation safe will incur some cost, and you should profile to make sure that cost is appropriate.

Comment: @user2407038 thanks a lot. You can answer this question, so that I can accept to finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `select` is explicitly telling you about this problem, and [lists which primitives](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html#cancellation-safety) can be safely used in this way without loosing messages. If your consumer is not one of those, unless the documentation for your library tells you it is cancellation safe, you should assume that it is not.

If your consumer is NOT cancellation safe, I believe you can do no better than to run two tasks, one which pulls data and pushes it to a shared queue which IS cancellation safe, and the other which performs the logic as described. In other words, copy data from your non-cancellation safe queue to a different cancellation safe queue.

Best practice will be based on how important performance is in your application - naturally pushing all your data to an intermediate queue which is cancellation safe will incur some cost, and you should profile to make sure that cost is appropriate.